# AutoMapper Skip All Null Properties, and then Allow some nulls

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to tell AutoMapper to skip all null properties (since my object has 50 properties) and then allow certain properties to be null afterwords?

In otherwords, I'd rather not "whitelist" 49 properties that should be skipped.  I'd rather default them ALL to be skipped, and then "whitelist" the one to ALLOW nulls.

The first part might of course look like this I imagine.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyClassA, MyClassB>()                
.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AfterMap to map certain properties manually and skip all other null properties:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyClassA, MyClassB>()
      .AfterMap((a,b) => b.Foo = a.Foo) // will be mapped if Foo is null
      .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was 100% the answer, and super easy!